# How the split points are chosen for continuous features in Decision Tree Classifiers

Tags: machine-learning, classification, python, scikit-learn, cart

Using the Iris data set, where the feature variables used are **sepal_width(x1)** and **petal_width(x2)**, scikit learn Decision Tree Classifier outputs the following tree -

**clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=6)**
**clf.fit(X,y)**

[image]

Now my question is how is the split points determined for the **continuous** feature variables x1 and x2?

I have found two type of answers(from different articles/blogs and here as well) -

1. Some say that if suppose **x1 = {2.0, 1.1, 5.3, 4.0}** and to decide the split points for x1, sort x1 to get **x1_sorted = {1.1, 2.0, 4.0, 5.3}** and calculate the mean of two consecutive points in this set to get the split points, i.e. **split_points = {1.55, 3, 4.65}**
2. While others say that the split points are all the distinct data points for the feature variable in question. So if **x1 = {2.0, 1.1, 5.3, 4.0}** then the split points would be, **split_points = {1.1, 2.0, 4.0, 5.3}**

Once the split points are determined, we can check for the best split using gini index.

But if one refers to the tree, it seems that its a combination of both, like X1 <= **0.8** and X1 <= **1.75** supports point 1 while X1 <= **1.6** seems to support point 2

Distinct Values in the petal_width data set = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 1. , 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, **1.6**, **1.7, 1.8**, 1.9, 2. , 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5]

1.6 is there in the data set, while average of 1.7 and 1.8 gives 1.75.

Is there any specific algorithm in play here?

Comment: Different reasonable implementations can differ in how they split. If you are specifically interested in this this particular implementation, it would probably be easiest to look into the source code and trace out what happens.